# Postgres query error

Tags: postgresql, mysql

I have a query in postgres

```
insert into c_d (select * from cd where ak = '22019763');
```

And I get the following error

```
ERROR:  column "region" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Comment: are you sure the c_d and and cd table have the same fields order? otherwise explicitly indicate the fields in your query

Comment: There are more fields in the c_d table than in the cd table. Are there any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2` depends entirely on *order* of the columns, which is part of the table definition. It will line each column of table1 up with the column of table2 with the same *order* value, regardless of names.

The problem you have here is whatever column from cd with the same order value as c_d of the table "region" has an incompatible type, and an implicit typecast is not available to clear the confusion.

`INSERT INTO SELECT *` statements are stylistically bad form unless the two tables are defined, and will forever be defined, **exactly** the same way. All it takes is for a single extra column to get added to cd, and you'll start getting errors about extraneous extra columns.

If it is at all possible, what I would suggest is explicitly calling out the columns within the `SELECT` statement. You can call a function to change type within each of the column references (or you could define a new type cast to do this implicitly -- see `CREATE CAST`), and you can use `AS` to set the column label to match that of your target column.

If you can't do this for some reason, indicate that in your question.

Comment: To clarify further, here's how to describe column names in such a statement (Postgres, copying rows into a table from another table): `INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: just to help y'all out if you really need to do this:
```SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_catalog = 'my_db' AND table_name = 'table1' 
EXCEPT
SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_catalog = 'my_db' AND table_name = 'table2';```
That will give you columns in table 1 that arent in table2. Be sure to run in reverse too.

Add those columns to each table to make the columns the same. I have a tabel with 900+ columns and this helped sooooo much.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the PostgreSQL [insert documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-insert.html) The syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
{ DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) | query }
```

which here would look something like:

```
INSERT INTO c_d (column1, column2...) select * from cd where ak = '22019763'
```

This is the syntax you want to use when inserting values from one table to another where the column types and order are not exactly the same.